# Change the color of the prompt *in* DOS (not the color of the whole DOS Prompt window)

Tags: windows, command-line, colors, ms-dos

In DOS, there is a "prompt" command that allows you to change the text that shows up to the left of your cursor.  I think the default is to just show the name of the current directory.

When I'm running long commands in DOS (below is a short example), I often need to scroll back to the beginning of the command output, which can be hard to find if you've been running a lot of commands in a row.

[image]

Is there a way to change the COLOR of the text in the prompt?  I know that I can put newlines in the prompt too, which does help, but since color codes are supported in other output, I'm hoping there's a way to change the prompt color too.

And the for the love of whatever you hold dear, please do not reply and tell me how to change the background color or text color of the overall DOS Prompt window.  I only want to change the color *in* the prompt, like how this is shown with bold (I guess StackExchange doesn't support color!):

**C:\Users\tuttlj**>mkdir npmtest

**C:\Users\tuttlj**>cd npmtest

**C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest**>npm install node-sass

node-sass@4.12.0 install C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest\node_modules\node-sass
node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\tuttlj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.12.0\win32-x64-57_binding.node

node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest\node_modules\node-sass
node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tuttlj\npmtest\package.json'
npm WARN npmtest No description
npm WARN npmtest No repository field.
npm WARN npmtest No README data
npm WARN npmtest No license field.

Comment: There is another topic related to your question on [how to customize the Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/427820/how-to-change-only-the-prompt-color-of-the-windows-command-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Here is an example done on Windows 10:

[image]

You may see above the two methods :
The [prompt command](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) and
the `PROMPT` environment variable.
Setting the environment variable for System or User gives the same result
as using the PROMPT command,
except that it will apply to all new Command Prompts.

The color sequences look like `$e[<number>m` and they can be combined.

This is documented by Microsoft in
[Text Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting).

The special functional terms, like `$P` for the current drive and path,
can be listed by running `prompt /?`.

Comment: Just what I needed!  Thanks for the documentation and a couple examples!

Comment: On Windows cmd (or Anaconda Prompt cmd), to change just the color of the prompt and leave whatever it was the way it was, use this command: `set "PROMPT=$e[44m%PROMPT%$e[0m"`. For example, if your original prompt was black `(base) E:\VSCodeProjects>`, it will change its color to blue.